# Cannot deploy simple Android app on my Galaxy phone

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-app-engine, gradle

I am in the early stages of building an Android app which will make use of the Google Maps API.  Towards this end, I will need to include the Google App Engine and Google Play Services dependencies.  Here is the current `build.gradle` file for my app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tbiegeleisen.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    //compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.24'
}
```

If I try to build my project from Android Studio, it appears to complete successfully.  But when I try to launch the app on my Samsung Galaxy phone, which is attached via USB, Android just sits there.  Also, my CPU usage goes up to near 100% and one time my laptop overheated and actually shut off.  Here is the error message I am getting:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

If I comment out the line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'` then the app deploys to my phone with no issue.

My hunch is that Android is trying to resolve some dependency or build issue and cannot, hence the high CPU usage.  What is strange (and inexplicable) to me is that the Gradle build *completes* successfully from within my IDE, but the problem shows up when trying to deploy to the phone.  Could my phone be the problem?  I hope that an expert can lend a helping hand here.

Some details to minimze the number of comments:

- My phone has USB debugging enabled (as mentioned I can deploy the app under certain conditions)
- My laptop is a Lenovo T410 running Windows 7 and has 8GB of RAM; no other significant programs are running besides Android Studio
- I am running Android Studio 1.2.2 with 64-bit Java 7 release 80

Comment: Can it launch in the emulator?

Comment: @John Android Studio doesn't even get that far unfortunately.  It hangs before the dialog appears asking where I want to deploy (phone or emulator) :-(

Comment: Also can you post the API version your Galaxy supports?

Comment: Working on that give me 2-3 minutes.

Comment: My Galaxy Note 2 phone is running Android version 4.3, which according to [this site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) supports API level 18.

Comment: I know what you're going to say: My phone is old and needs to be upgraded.  But, if this be the case, it is strange that Android Studio is giving up _before_ even asking whether I want to deploy by phone or by emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play Services are ***huge*** and can cause problems. 
Try to [selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).
Alternatively, try to disable proguard.
What's inside your libs folder ?

Comment: When I comment out Play Services and instead includenApp Engine, I get the same result with Amdroid Studio freezing and 100% CPU usage.

Comment: You rock, and your answer totally solved the problem with Google Play Services.  But now I still have a problem with the Google App Engine plugin.  I don't want to create a discussion fest here, but if you could provide a resource for how to get this plugin working, that would be much appreciated.